# NGINX Logs have no jsonPayload field in Stackdriver

Tags: nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a basic nginx deployment serving static content running on a GKE cluster. I have configured Stackdriver Logging for the cluster as per instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/logging) (I enabled logging for an existing cluster), and I also enabled the Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring feature explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/). The logging itself seems to be working fine, as I can see the logs from nginx in Stackdriver.

I am trying to create some log-based metrics like number of fulfilled 2xx requests, but all I am getting in the log entries in Stackdriver is the `textPayload` field. From what I understand, enabling Stackdriver Monitoring on the cluster spins up some Fluentd agents (which I can see if I run `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`), and they should have an nginx log parser enabled by default (as per documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging)). However, none of the log entries that show up in Stackdriver have the `jsonPayload` field that should be there for structured logs.

I'm using the default `log_format` config for nginx, and I've verified that the default nginx parser is able to parse the logs my application is writing (I copied the [default Fluentd nginx parser plugin regular expression](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/parser_nginx) and a log entry from my application to [this tool](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com) and it was able to parse the entry)

I'm sure I must be missing something, but I can't figure out what.

Edit:

For reference, here is my NGINX log format:

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent"';
```

And I have tried the following so far:

- Upgrade my k8s cluster from version 1.11.5 to 1.11.6 (due to issue with structured logging in version 1.11.4, which was fixed in 1.11.6)
- Downgrade from version 1.11.6 to 1.11.3
- Make a brand new cluster with the GCP console (version 1.10.9), with Stackdriver Monitoring and Stackdriver Logging options enabled and deploy my application on that. Still no `jsonPayload` field, only `textPayload`.

So far, none of these have solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After being in contact with Google Cloud Support, we were able to devise a workaround for this issue, although the root cause still remains unknown.

The workaround is to define the NGINX log format itself as a JSON string. This will allow the Google-Fluentd parser to correctly parse the payload as a JSON object. This is the only solution that has worked for me so far.

For reference, the log format I used is:

```
log_format json_combined escape=json
'{'
'"time_local":"$time_local",'
'"remote_addr":"$remote_addr",'
'"remote_user":"$remote_user",'
'"request_method":"$request_method",'
'"request":"$request",'
'"status": "$status",'
'"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent",'
'"request_time":"$request_time",'
'"http_referrer":"$http_referer",'
'"http_user_agent":"$http_user_agent"'
'}';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log json_combined;
```

Answer (score 3):

We are formatting logs in a way that Cloud Logging directly understands them like this:

```
        log_format json_combined escape=json
          '{'
            '"httpRequest":{'
              '"requestMethod":"$request_method",'
              '"requestUrl":"$scheme://$host$request_uri",'
              '"requestSize":$request_length,'
              '"status":$status,'
              '"responseSize":$bytes_sent,'
              '"userAgent":"$http_user_agent",'
              '"remoteIp":"$remote_addr",'
              '"referer":"$http_referer",'
              '"latency":"${request_time}s",'
              '"protocol":"$server_protocol",'
              '"request":"$request",'
              '"remoteUser":"$remote_user"'
            '}'
          '}';
```

This way you don't need to use fluentd. Here you can find the reference: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#HttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Kubernetes 1.11.4, by any chance? It's a known issue with [Beta release 1.11.4](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/release-guide#beta_release_1114). The fix is available in [Beta Update (Kubernetes 1.11.6)](https://issuetracker.google.com/121412213).
Please confirm your version.

Comment: I was running version 1.11.5. I tried upgrading to the latest version (1.11.6-gke.2), but that did not fix the issue. I then tried downgrading to version 1.11.3-gke.24 (as suggested as a workaround in the link you provided), but the issue is still not resolved, there is still no jsonPayload field in the Stackdriver logs, only the textPayload field.

Comment: Just for a small sanity check, I created a brand new cluster (version 1.10.9, the recommended one) with the Stackdriver Logging and Stackdriver Monitoring options enabled in the GCP Console and deployed my application on that. The logs on the new cluster are still not structured, and the same problem persists. I'm starting to believe that I am missing some step or config required for structured logging to be enabled, or that the default log format from NGINX does not actually match what the logging agent expects. I have updated the original post with what I've tried so far.

Comment: Just to make sure that you write log entry with a structured (JSON) payload [1]. 
It expects a  --payload-type that could be either a text or JSON.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#write_entry